# Xubuntu how to check used and free disk space

Tags: xubuntu, disk-usage

How can I check free and used disk space on Xubuntu?

On Ubuntu, this was very easy to do, but I don't see a program that accomplishes this now with Xubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as simple as `df -h` command, sample output below

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root  290G  5.3G  270G   2% /
none                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         375M  916K  374M   1% /run
none                          5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                          1.9G  700K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none                          100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     228M   45M  172M  21% /boot
```

Comment: thanks.  Do you know how to change the size of the temp files?   I have undev holding `7.8GB and using 4kb`, tmpfs/tmp `7.8 and 20kb`, tmpfs/run `3.2 and 836kb`, none/run/shm `7.8 and 88k`, and tmpfs/home/dustin `7.8 and 644k`.  I don't think I need all that space allocated that is being unused.

Comment: welcome. regarding your question, i think you should post it as new question here. but i think you should not delete anything from that folders you mentioned because they are used by your whole system, i guess.